# How to test against a legacy Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am writing a piece of software that needs to connect and integrate with a legacy Oracle database, which is only running in production (i.e. no development server available for testing) and on which I have absolutely no control.

The legacy system uses Oracle 9i R2, which seems to have been released in 2004 [1], i.e. 15 years ago. 9i R2 does not seem to be available anywhere for download anymore [2].

I would like to run a local copy of a system similar to the production database in my environment to test against it. However, I have no idea how I can get my hand on a running 9i R2 server (and client), which preferably runs on a modern Linux box. Is this even possible?

How would you suggest to proceed in such situation? I am worried I will have to conduct testing directly on the production system.

[1] https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/92-rn-01-134091.pdf

[2] https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: You can install Oracle 9.2.0 yourself.
To do this, you need to download and install CentOS 4.1. http://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/4.1/isos/i386/
And install Oracle 9.2.
Installation Guide https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/oracle-db-9i-installation-on-rhel-and-centos-4

Comment: Thanks! However the installation guide you suggest links to Oracle Technology Network, which does not contain any link to Oracle 9.2.0 as of now. Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download. They say that "The software is available as a media or FTP request for those customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any edition." (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)  However, there is no mension of Oracle 9i.

Comment: If you want to download an unsupported version, you need a support contract. Everything else is simply violating Oracle's license rules.

Comment: Try to take the distribution from the owner of the production database.